# how to use RowActivated in RadGridView with single click

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, telerik

I am using telerik control for my app,I am using RowActivated event but its working for double click . I want to for single click. Is this possible.
Can I over right behavior of this event by the dependency or other way?